# CSS: How to attach an arrow to a div and make it overlap the border

Tags: css, popover

I am trying to make a popover with an error, but I am having trouble making the arrow appear above the border of the div I am attaching it to. I would appreciate any help.

This is what I have so far...

[image: This is what I have...]

This is the CSS code I am using, but cant get it to work:

1.DIV for the entire popover:

```
<div class="info-popover">
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="arrow"></div>
</div>
```

2.CSS for each:

```
.info-popover {
    height: 250px;
    margin-top: -255px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
}

.info-popover .inner {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #003366;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    height: 240px;
    margin-top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.info-popover .arrow {
    background: url("/images/dock/popover-arrow.png") no-repeat scroll center -5px transparent;
    height: 15px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

CSS solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/wn7JN/

```
.bubble 
{
position: relative;
width: 400px;
height: 250px;
padding: 0px;
background: #FFFFFF;
border: #000 solid 1px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
}

.bubble:after 
{
content: "";
position: absolute;
bottom: -25px;
left: 175px;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 25px 25px 0;
border-color: #FFFFFF transparent;
display: block;
width: 0;
z-index: 1;
}

.bubble:before 
{
content: "";
position: absolute;
top: 250px;
left: 174px;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 26px 26px 0;
border-color: #000 transparent;
display: block;
width: 0;
z-index: 0;
}
```

Comment: I was about to suggest since this is much more CSS3 than using images (since you tagged the Question CSS3). However, I prefered to stick to the question since everytime I suggest different thing my answers get negative votes...

Comment: Indeed, I figured since CSS3 was tagged and this answers "CSS: How to attach an arrow to a div and make it overlap the border" That it would be a good approach to solving this.

Comment: This is a much better approach. Perhaps, Santz, I should have said "any help on this or a better solution is appreciated". I guess I can do that next time. I wish I could accept your answer as well since I will use that solution when creating a css file for ie7, as it does not support these css3 pseudo-elements... I have upvoted your answer. Thank you for the efforts. This solution fitted nicely...

Answer (score 7):

Easiest way:

HTML:

```
<div class="meow">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.meow { 
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 30px;
  background: linear-gradient(#333, #222);
  -o-border-radius: 4px;
  -ms-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.meow:after {
  content: " ";
  border-top: 11px solid #222;
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
  position: relative;
  top: 111px;
  right: -140px;
}
```

Live preview: **[CodePen.io](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/avzwdX)**

Just do some few edits.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

HTML

```
<div class="info-popover">
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <p class="arrow"></p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.info-popover {
    position: relative;
    /* any other CSS */
}

.arrow {
    background: url("/images/dock/popover-arrow.png") no-repeat 0 0;
    height: 15px;
    width: 20px; /* width of arrow image? */
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -15px;
    left: 0; margin: 0 auto; right: 0; /* to center the arrow */
}
```